# count number of exposures to each ad

Tags: sql

I have an ad_history table with `'id'` `'ad_id'` `'customer_id'` and `'display_date'` listed. 
[ad_history table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEHjw.png)

I'm trying to count the number of times each ad was viewed by a customer. This is what I've got so far:

```
Select ad_id, count(ad_id) as exposures from ad_history group by ad_id order by ad_id asc;
```

Gets me these results: [results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6vv3.png) which are clearly incorrect, as none of the first 10 ad_id's are listed more than 5 times in the original table.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:
when you need anything in ascending order, you don't need to write it explicitly, ascending order is by default.

```
Select ad_id, count(customer_id) as exposures from ad_history 
group by ad_id 
order by ad_id
```

Comment: That gets me the same thing I had before: http://i.imgur.com/AfDuNUI.png

Comment: the values in exposures are incorrect, if you look at the first table I posted there should be 1 for ad_id 1, 2, for ad_id 2, 3 for ad_id 3, and then 1 for ad_id 4

Comment: what u get after execute the query..it will be good if you post the result also

Comment: I wasn't changing my requirements, I'm just saying what the results for the table would be if the code were correct.

Comment: the response to your comment was the result of the query you suggested

Comment: yes, you should get just your comment of this "1 for ad_id 1, 2, for ad_id 2, 3 for ad_id 3, and then 1 for ad_id 4"

Comment: my first response to you was the result of this query

Comment: The answer of @Fahmina is exactly what you want, maybe you are doing some strange when you test it.

Comment: could it be an issue with the table? I copy and pasted her response in mysql workbench.

Comment: Yes maybe you have some kind of error, the sql query is ok, you can test it here: [link code sql](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_sql_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMX2ZjN2FlN3dBSFk)